# Delegate events for subelements including the current element

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a general jQuery code which will catch *all the `submit` events of `<form>` subelements including the container element (in case it's a form)*.

The cases are:

#### The container is a form

```
<form>
    <button>hi</button>
</form>
```

#### The container is another element containing forms

```
<div>
    <form>
        <button>submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

What's the cleanest code to do this?

My current solution is the following:

```
function submit(e) {
   // do something
}

$(containerSelectorOrjQueryObject).on("submit", "form", submit);
$(containerSelectorOrjQueryObject).on("submit", submit);
```

However, I'd be happy to know if there is a better solution, using just one `on` call.

Comment: "in case it's a form" - I hope you're not suggesting your forms might be nested! That's invalid HTML.

Comment: what about `$(document).on('submit','form', submit);`

Comment: @Roamer-1888 The thing is I want to include the sub element forms and also the container if it's a form. I don't care if the user provides (in)valid HTML. My scope is write my code in the cleanest way.

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali I don't want to catch all forms from `document`. So, it is not  a good solution.

Comment: Create a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and show us a few sample forms that you want to attach the event handler to, and a few that you don't, so we can write you a solution.

Comment: @Danbopes There are just the two cases from my post: when the container itself is a form and when the container has form sub elements. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzo43y7r/).

Comment: @IonicăBizău, OK I think I understand better now - the HTML will not necessarily be your own. I think the best you can do is `$(containerSelector).parent().on("submit", "form", submit);`. That will cater for the container being a form, or any element(s) within the container being form(s).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I also thought that `parent()` could be a solution, but it isn't.  I don't want to select all the forms from the same level.

Comment: OK, but that's a constraint not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class attribute for this as a way to set up a delegate to catch the submit event of any child form no matter what the parent element is. Because it is a delegate, this will also catch anything fired by elements that have been dynamically added as well.

Example that includes a single form scenario, multiple forms in div scenario, and a button to add a form dynamically:

```js
var alreadyAdded;

function submit(e) {
    // do something
    alert(e.target.name);
    return false;
}

$("body").on("submit", ".outerContainer", submit);

$("#addAnotherDynamically").on("click", function(e) {
    if (typeof(alreadyAdded) === "undefined") {
        alreadyAdded = true;
        $("#test2").append("<form name='form4'><button>submit 4</button></form>");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <form id="test1" name="form1" class="outerContainer">
        <button>submit 1</button>
    </form>
    
    <div id="test2" class="outerContainer">
        <form name="form2">
            <button>submit 2</button>
        </form>
        <form name="form3">
            <button>submit 3</button>
        </form>        
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <button id="addAnotherDynamically">Add another form</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit events, like other event,  bubbles across the DOM, so attaching an submit event listener to the `form` itself or to any of its parents will work and you can even cancel your submit there.

To always get the `form` in which the submit was triggered use `e.target` instead of `this` within the event listener method.

See this example:

```js
function onSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('d3').innerHTML += 'Submit catched in ' + e.currentTarget.tagName + '#' + e.currentTarget.id + ' for ' + e.target.tagName + '#' + e.target.id + '<br/>';  
}

$(function(){
  $('#d1').on('submit', onSubmit);
  $('#f2').on('submit', onSubmit);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
   <form id="f1">
  <input type="submit" value="Event Listener on DIV" />
  </form>  
</div>


<div id="d2">
   <form id="f2">
  <input type="submit" value="Event Listener on Form" />
  </form>  
</div>

<div id="d3">
</div>
```

Running it and clicking on the buttons you can see that using the same `on` call you can attach evest to the form itself or its parent and it will work as expected.

So, you can go with only the line below and it will work fine:

```
$(containerSelectorOrjQueryObject).on("submit", submit);
```

Comment: This still uses two `on` calls. Not a real solution to my problem.

Comment: the two `on` call code is just an example that in fact does no matter if you use the `form` or `div`, My last paragraphs concludes that you need only one call and I also said which one...

Comment: I agree it will work for this case, but it is doesn't support delegated events.

Comment: What do you mean? The DIV is handling the submit event which was fired by its child, this is event delegation... Provide a better example then...

Comment: This will not work for dynamically added elements. By *delegation* I mean to catch the events (e.g. `"submit"`) for elements that are added after the handler is attached.